# How to create a table with rows in DialogFlow fulfillment index.js

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a table with a 3 columns and a row using node.js in DialogFlow fulfillment index.js file to display it in Google Assistant. But I'm not able to make it since I'm very new. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [Table Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#table_cards).

```
// Simple table
conv.ask('This is a simple table example.')
conv.ask(new Table({
  dividers: true,
  columns: ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'],
  rows: [
    ['row 1 item 1', 'row 1 item 2', 'row 1 item 3'],
  ],
}))
```

If you are new to fulfillment using webhooks, consider completing [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/) to get started.

Hope this helps.